# NextJS <Link> not linking to another page after authentication

Tags: next.js

I am using nextJS authentication to log through sign(). After the login is authenticated, a link popsup that should navigate to the dashboard page. However, I am unable to get it to work and I am getting a 404 error.

Here is what my relevant files in my project directory looks like. The pages.tsx file is where the sign in buttons are rendered in. I've tried putting the dashboard file in the root directory, and also in the app directory without the pages folder but that has not worked either.

```
PROJECTNAME
  /app
    pages.tsx 
  /pages
    dashboard.tsx
  /components 
    buttons.tsx
```

Here is the buttons.tsx code and the area I'm having trouble with is the  code in the if statement:

```
'use client';

import Dashboard from '../app/pages/dashboard';
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from 'next-auth/react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';

export function SignInButton() {
    const { data: session, status } = useSession();
    console.log(session, status);
  
    if (status === 'loading') {
      return <>...</>;
    }

    if (status === "authenticated") {

      return (
        <Link href="/dashboard">
          <p>Dashboard</p>
        </Link>
      );
       

    }
    
  
    return <button className="btn btn-secondary"onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>;
}

export function SignOutButton() {
    return <button className="btn btn-primary"onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>;
}
```

Here is the dashboard.tsx code:

```
export default function dashboard() {

    return (
        <div>
            <p> TEST </p>        
        </div>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to modify your file directory as so `/src/app/dashboard/page.tsx` Check out the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#pages) on how the app directory works

```
PROJECTNAME
  /app 
    /dashboard
       page.tsx 
   page.tsx 
  /components 
    buttons.tsx
```

Also modify your dashboard component:

```
export default function Dashboard() {

    return (
        <div>
            <p> TEST </p>        
        </div>
    )

}
```

Then modify the `SignInButton` component:

```
'use client';

import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from 'next-auth/react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'


export function SignInButton() {
    const router = useRouter();

    const { data: session, status } = useSession();
    console.log(session, status);
  
    if (status === 'loading') {
      return <>...</>;
    }

    if (status === "authenticated") {

      router.push(/dashboard)
       

    }
    
  
    return <button className="btn btn-secondary"onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>;
}

export function SignOutButton() {
    return <button className="btn btn-primary"onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>;
}
```

Learn more about the [useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#userouter-hook) hook for navigating through routes in NextJs 14.

Comment: Really appreciate the comment. I've tried doing what youve mentioned and its still giving me a 404 error. Opening the console for more information just shows a 404 error aswell. I'll add some screenshots to show you what I got but its exactly what you've commented

[project screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/yHbxKB6)

Comment: I've modified the answer! Rename pages.tsx to page.tsx

Answer (score 0):

The issue is evident: you are attempting to import the "dashboard" from the components directory, but it is located in the pages directory.

```js
import Dashboard from '@/pages/dashboard';
```